# Rust macros - structs, enums, conversion

Tags: rust

have question related to (maybe) rust macros, or some other smart way to implement this.

1. Code below comes from 3rd-party and can't be modified

```rust
pub struct Message0;

pub struct Message1;

pub struct Message {
   pub payload: Option<Payload>,
}

pub enum Payload {
   PayloadMessage0(Message0),
   PayloadMessage1(Message1),
}

pub fn third_party_send(msg: Message) {
   // ...
}
```

2. It is desired to somehow implement this function ( or some other variant that will not require to implement separate functions for each of Message0 & Message1 types )

```rust
pub fn send<T>(specific_msg: T) {
    third_party_send(Message {
        payload: Some(Payload::PayloadMessage???(specific_msg)),
    });
}
```

I am new to rust, still a bit confused by macros & generics ....

Comment: Start here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html.   this might be helpful as well https://oswalt.dev/2021/06/using-generic-types-in-rust/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get around having to create a function for each variant, but you
can create a macro doing it for you.
I'd then wrap those in a trait to convert the `Message?` to a `Payload` and enable your generic function:

```rust
pub trait ToPayload {
    fn to_payload(self) -> Payload;
}
macro_rules! to_payload {
    ($message:ident, $payload:ident) => {
        impl ToPayload for $message {
            fn to_payload(self) -> Payload {
                Payload::$payload(self)
            }
        }
    }
}

to_payload!{ Message0, PayloadMessage0 }
to_payload!{ Message1, PayloadMessage1 }

pub fn send<T: ToPayload>(specific_msg: T) {
    third_party_send(Message {
        payload: Some(specific_msg.to_payload())
    });
}

fn main() {
    send(Message0);
    send(Message1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6db66984f80366c5eb30d726f9bdbb7f)

With the unstable feature `concat_idents` you could remove some repetition from the macro invocation

```rust
#![feature(concat_idents)]

macro_rules! to_payload {
    ($message:ident) => {
        impl ToPayload for $message {
            fn to_payload(self) -> Payload {
                use Payload::*;
                concat_idents!(Payload, $message) (self)
            }
        }
    };
}

to_payload! { Message0 }
```

Comment: Yep, this one will work. Interesting if there is a way to take one type - `Message0` and make from it another type `PayloadMessage0` inside macro. I know that proc-macro will work for this but since I can't modify 3rd-party code, proc-macro is not useful in this case.

Comment: Surely you can - just implement `From<Message{1,0}> for Payload` (or another trait if you can't because of orphan rules) and take `impl Into<Payload>`.

Comment: I mean for example: `($message:ident, $payload:ident)` if it is possible to take only `$message:ident` and construct from it inside macro something like `Payload$message` . So the end result will be -`to_payload!{ Message0 }` and not `to_payload{ Message0, PayloadMessage0 }`

Comment: Yes it's possible (on nightly), see the update.